# Adding Firebase Realtime Database to an Android app using the instructions of the offical website yields error

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add Firebase Realtime Database to my app and I use the instructions of the offical website (https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#groovy). Unforunately I get errors. The strange thing is that you can use between the instructions in the programming language Kotlin and Groovy but not in Java. As I am using Java in my app, I don't really know what to do as on the offical website you can only choose between the other programming languages. I tried the instructions for both and I always get an error when trying to complile my build.gradle file.

Here is how my file looks like on Project level:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.nav_version = '2.5.3'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    // ...

    // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.0' apply false
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here on App level:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'


    // Add the Google services Gradle plugin
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")


}

apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.game"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        viewBinding {
            enabled = true
        }

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    namespace 'com.example.game'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4"


    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.4.0"))


    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))

}
```

I get the error

```
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.3.0')
```

Do you know what the problem is and how to fix it? The very strange and not well explained point on the official website it, why they exclude Java as a programming language in Step 3 of their instructions and use Groovy instead while in Step 4 the Java option is mentioned again (and all of a sudden no Groovy option anymore). This is very confusing.

Comment: You are missing gradle classpath in ```build.gradle(project-level)``` or using wrong gradle version. try changing version to ```7.3``` rather ```7.3.0```

Comment: you can remove the ```id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false``` line from ```plugin``` block it will works

Comment: Have you tried to use one of the latest [versions](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin)?

Comment: @AlexMamo: Actually I am not sure which version I am using because in the `plugin` there is not version number specified but just in the dependencies `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'` So most probably I am using version 8.0.0 altough it is not in the plugins. The problem with the link you gave me is the same problem as in the Firebase website. There is no instruction about how to do the updates for Java but just for Kotlin and Groove. As I am using Java, I don't know what to do. For the Firebase instructions I used both Kotlin and Groove instructions but they both did not work

Comment: @ChiragThummar: Thanks Chirag for your comments. I tried both of your options using `id 'com.android.application' version '7.3' apply false` (instead of 7.3.0 as you said) but I get the error "Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:". When using your second option to remove `id 'com.android.application' version '7.3' apply false` I get the error "Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.4.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:"

Comment: @ChiragThummar: Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: remove plugin block and add ``` classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'``` to your dependencies block in project level ```build.gradle```

Comment: @ChiragThummar: Thanks for your answer. Actually the grandle sync now works without problem altough I have not removed the plugin block (because I was not sure what you meant by that). Do I really have to remove it, altough for now I dont get any error from build.gradle? I have not yet tested a Firebase query, so I don't know if the database connection works (I will test that later)

Comment: plugin block is used in new gradle version so if you don't need you can try removing.

Comment: @ChiragThummar: Thanks for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. What do you mean by "plugin block" and "new grandle version"? Further, I don't know if I need it or not. What effect does it have to use the "plugin block" (I still don't know what this is)

Comment: @ChiragThummar: Thanks for your answer. Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.